# Redis Custom DataStructure

Tags: database, redis

Data Field as

```
  typedef struct Info
  {
     std::string Name;
     std::string Address;
     ...
     So on
  };
```

and Want to store data in `Redis` Here. there may a instance when 
some of the field of structure can repeat. How can i make above struct in `Redis` and store.
There is one condition. if data of same value exist. don't overwrite. add new row.

Like this but it's in Programming Language

```
 std::list<Info> infoList_;
```

And able to search also;

Comment: What do you mean by 'some of the field of structure can repeat'? And you want to search it in what way?

Comment: lets say there is field of `state` in `Info`. For multiple people the value can be same. and I want to search people of `age` of 24. Like this. [searching of data is not important ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis don't provide a data structure that can store a list of complex object structure.

But you can maybe use a redis module like :

- rejson : A native JSON data type for Redis : http://redismodules.com/modules/rejson/
- redissearch : High performance full text search engine : http://redismodules.com/modules/redisearch/

Both modules can store complex data structure.

Comment: Lets say if I have entry in `Redis` Like this.  
these are Keys    `ABC:22:1`, ` ABC:22.2`, `ABC:22:3`.
can i somehow access them with `ABC:22:*` or "ABC:". Yes then Please

Comment: I got it.. `SCAN 0 MATCH `*ABC:*` COUNT 1000

Comment: Next i want to know, how to get number of keys of matching pattern

Comment: You can't do this. The only way i see is to assign keys with pattern ABC:22:* for example in database 1 then keys with pattern ABC:23:* in database 2 and so on. Then if you want to know how many keys with pattern ABC:22:* redis contains, you have to execute `SELECT 1` then `DBSIZE` commands

Comment: `DBSIZE` [Return the number of keys in the currently-selected database.]. it won't say how many keys are there with matching pattern.

Comment: Can i filler the data on the basis of there value.